# Should it be in a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Do I have to put code from .cpp in a namespace from corresponding .h or it's enough to just write using declaration?

```
//file .h
namespace a
{
/*interface*/
class my
{
};
}

//file .cpp

using a::my; // Can I just write in this file this declaration and
             // after that start to write implementation, or
             // should I write:

namespace a //everything in a namespace now
{
//Implementation goes here
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I consider more appropriate to surround all the code that is meant to be in the namespace within a `namespace a { ... }` block, as that is semantically what you are doing: you are defining elements within the `a` namespace. But if you are only defining members then both things will work.

When the compiler finds `void my::foo()`, it will try to determine what `my` is, and it will find the `using a::my`, resolve `my` from that and understand that you are defining the `a::my::foo` method.

On the other hand this approach will fail if you are using free functions:

```
// header
namespace a {
   class my { // ... 
   };
   std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream& o, my const & m );
}
// cpp
using a::my;
using std;
ostream & operator<<( ostream & o, my const & m ) {
   //....
}
```

The compiler will happily translate the above code into a program, but what it is actually doing is declaring `std::ostream& a::operator<<( std::ostream&, a::my const & )` in the header file --without implementation--, and defining `std::ostream& ::operator<<( std::ostream &, a::my const & )` in the cpp file, which is a different function. Using Koening lookup, whenever the compiler sees `cout << obj` with `obj` of type `a::my`, the compiler will look in the enclosing namespaces of `cout` and `my` (`std`, and `a`) and will find that there is an `a::operator<<` declared but never defined in `namespace a`. It will compile but not link your code.

Comment: +1. What's in the namespace is in the `namespace{}`. Things like this don't demand indentation so there is really no trouble.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you can have just using a::my and then just implement the methods, like

```
using a::my;

void my::doSomething() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do it.  But, *should* you?

It's an uncommon practice, and it will probably lead to a proliferation of `using a::Type;` for every type from namespace 'a' used in the .cc file.  Whether that is a good thing is for you to decide, but I'd vote against it :)

Comment: You can also use `using namespace a;` and implement the code without needing to have a big namespace a{} in the code. Namespace declarations are for headers.